# Left circular bit shift

Tags: java, bit-shift

I have to write a function that does a left circular shift of the bits of y positions.
For example, if I put: ***01011000*** and ***2*** as the y, the function has to return ***01100001***.

I have tried to use `Integer.rotateLeft()` but it seems to be useless for this.

Comment: On only 8 bits? You could identify the two bits that would be rotated out, rotate everything else with <<, then move the two bits back to the start and or that with the other number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work I think:

```
int rotate_8bits_left(int val, int y) {
    // amend y to the range [0, 7] with this:
    // y = ((y % 8) + 8) % 8;
    // or better, with this:
    y = y & 0x7;
    // do the rotation
    return ((val << y) & 0xFF) | (val >> (8-y));
}
```

Let's explain the different parts:

```
// move val left y bits:
(val << y)
```

Above however keeps the bits that get beyond the 8th bit, so we need to truncate them, so we go with:

```
// move val left y bits and truncate anything beyond the 8th bit:
(val << y) & 0xFF
```

Now we need to add the bits that went out, to the beginning. We can calculate the bit that went out to the left by just moving to the right:

```
// move to the right, 8-y bits
val >> (8-y)
```

If we now glue together the two parts, we would get the rotation:

```
int new_val = ((val << y) & 0xFF) | (val >> (8-y));
```

Now for the first part, we want to handle y that might not be in the range [0, 8]. We can amend y to this range, before using it, with:

```
y = ((y % 8) + 8) % 8;
```

The expression above fixes both negative and positive values of y, if y is negative the modulo would return a negative value in the range [-7, -1], then by adding 8 we get back to the positive range. We have to do modulo again, for the case where y was positive and adding 8 to fix the negative case took it back to be above 8. The second modulo fixes this.

But we can achieve the same amendment for y with a more simple approach, by leaving only the 3 first bits that encounter for the range [0, 7], treating 8 as 0, this can be done with the following expression, that works well for both negative and positive values of y:

```
y = y & 0x7;
```